# Printing loop iterations in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm just starting with assembly, I got some basic stuff down like puts and strlen but some of the concepts don't make sense.

I'm trying to implement a basic loop and print the counter at every iteration. Here is my code so far:

```
%include 'functions.asm' ;contains print and exit


section .data
    msg db 'loop', 0x0a, 0x00

section .bss

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov ecx, 0

repeat:
    cmp ecx, 10
    jz done
    push ecx         ;line 18
    mov ecx, msg     ;line 19
    call print
    pop ecx          ;line 21
    inc ecx
    jmp repeat

done:
    call exit
```

This works. But the output is 'loop\n' n times. I'm trying to get '0\n1\n2\n3\n....n\n'.

So far this is what I tried:
  - remove the lines 18, 19 and 21. Segfaults, not sure why.
  - replace line 19 with add ecx, '0'. Segfault as well.

Also, I'm not sure why cmp works. Should't I compare the value in the register with cmp byte[ecx], 10 instead of the register itself ?
Same with inc, it increases the value contained in ecx ? So if I do inc [ecx], 1, it's going to increase the value at the address contained inside ecx ? So xor ecx, ecx,  inc [ecx], 1 should increase the value at memory address 0x00000000 by 1 ?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you have some custom `print` function that prints a string pointed to by `ecx`. You might have `print_int` or similar function that you can use directly. If not, then you were on the right track by adding `'0'` however you need to place your string into memory and pass a pointer to it. One possible solution:

```
%include 'functions.asm' ;contains print and exit

section .data
    msg db '#', 0x0a, 0x00  ; the # is a placeholder for the digit

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov ecx, 0

repeat:
    cmp ecx, 10
    je done
    push ecx
    add cl, '0'
    mov [msg], cl
    mov ecx, msg
    call print
    pop ecx          ;line 21
    inc ecx
    jmp repeat

done:
    call exit
```

Arguably simpler version that uses the text for counting:

```
%include 'functions.asm' ;contains print and exit

section .data
    msg db '0', 0x0a, 0x00

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov ecx, msg
repeat:
    call print
    inc byte [msg]
    cmp byte [msg], '9'
    jbe repeat

done:
    call exit
```

As for your other question, yes, `[]` means memory reference so don't use that if you want to operate on the register directly.

Comment: Okay I understand why this works. Isn't there a simpler / more elegant way to do this though ?

Comment: Of course you could have your counter in the string ... as to whether that's simpler or more elegant is up to discussion. Also obviously if you have a print for integers, as I said.

Comment: @JonNimrod: yes, write a loop that creates a whole string in memory, and pass that to `print` once. This is *much* more efficient than invoking a print function 10 times.  e.g. `mov ecx, (10<<8) + '0'` (or `mov ecx, \`0\n\`` backticks) to init a register holding the two bytes `0\n', then you can `mov [edi], cx` / `add edi, 2` / `inc ecx` / `cmp cl, '9'` / `jbe .loop` to increment a pointer and keep storing 2-byte sequences of digit + newline, looping until the low byte of ECX (which gets stored as the first byte of each group because x86 is little endian) has exceeded the ASCII code for `'9'`.